# Refresh a div container with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, So I have this chunk of code:

```
    <div class="tags-column" id="tags">

      <h2>Tags</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @presenter.tag_counters.each do |tag_counter| %>
          <li class="<%= tag_counter.tag %>">
            <%= link_to case_snitches_path(@project, tags: tag_counter.tag), { class: (params[:tags] == tag_counter.tag ? "active tag" : "tag")} do %>
              <span class="tag-name"><%= tag_counter.tag %></span>
              <span class="tag-counts">
                <%= tag_count(tag_counter, :pending) %>
                <%= tag_count(tag_counter, :missing) %>
                <%= tag_count(tag_counter, :reporting) %>
              </span>
            <% end %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

The page itself is much larger than this. But using JQuery I only want to update this portion on some event. I can't seem to find a suitable answer to this question. Here is the current JS I'm using that is not working:

```
$(".tags-column").load(document.URL + " .tags-column")
```

If I do this it just duplicates the div and screws everything up.

Comment: Do you have more than one class of `tags-column` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to update html of the div

```
 $(".tags-column").html("some HTML contents");
```

or

```
$("#tags").html("some HTML contents");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to re-render the page like when it was first loaded, which is not possible with javascript. What you have to do is to load the content of the file that you want to load and then remove the old content. You could process it to show just the content you want.

So first get the content of the url and place it in a new div like this:

```
$(".NEW-tags-column").load("yourfile.html");
```

Remember that the load function places the content of the file in the selector `$(".tags-column")`. I don't understand why you added the selector to the file here `load(document.URL + " .tags-column")`?

Then remove the old content of the `<div>`:

```
$(".tags-column").remove();
```

This way you will update your content.

Comment: *"don't understand why you added the selector"* ... because `load()` lets you only load page fragments by adding selector after space in url argument. See docs